# Resolving conflicts in GIT for a Pull-request on forked repo

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution

In short, i forked a repo, then created a branch from master, did some coding, pushed branch to origin, created a PR, the PR cannot be merged as it contains conflicts [guessing due to the work of other people]

```
<<<<<<<
code on master
======
my code
>>>>>>>
```

I then checked out master, did a pull, checked out my branch, merged master into it, resolved the conflicts, made a commit, pushed the commit, the PR updated with the new commit, the same file still has a conflict like this bellow

```
<<<<<<<
======
my code
>>>>>>>
```

Nothing i've tried seems to work, any ideas?
Also, what would be the correct way of solving this from the start?

Comment: Are you saying that you committed the unresolved conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to answer my own question as to what i was doing wrong, might help someone.
When a conflict occurs on a `pull request`, checkout the branch you are merging into, update it, checkout the branch which is being merged, rebase the main branch onto it, resolve any conflicts and push with the `-f` flag, also it might be good practice to do a **interactive rebase** to squash all commits and makes the history cleaner.